# Writing binary in c++ and read in python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, binary

I would like to store a series of numbers to a binary file using c++, to open later using python. Currently I have the following script in c++ named *writer.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::ofstream outFile;
  outFile.open("binaryFile.bin", std::ios::binary);
  int number = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    number += i;
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&number), sizeof(int));
  }
  outFile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Which when compiling as

```
g++ -o writerTest.x writer.cpp
```

and run as

```
./writerTest.x
```

produce a binary file named "binaryFile.bin".

I then try to read this using python with the following script named *reader.py*:

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv

path = str(argv[1])
x = np.fromfile(path)
print x, type(x)
```

Running this as 
    python reader.py binaryFile.bin
produce the following result

```
[  2.12199579e-314   1.27319747e-313   3.18299369e-313   5.94158822e-313
9.54898106e-313] <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Which obviously is not what I was hoping for. What am I doing wrong, and how should this be done properly?

Comment: You cannot just cast and write into a file, you must serialize your data to a known format (an existing one, or one you create yourself).

Comment: You are writing integers and reading floats, that cannot work. (Binary)

Comment: @spectras: In practice, assuming an optimizer that is not overly aggressive and a "reasonable" platform, OP's code is likely to work in most cases.  In theory, you do have to bit-mask and reconstruct the thing into a series of characters, but meh.

Comment: @Kevin: …and that the python interpreter was compiled with the same compiler as his code. In the end, that's a lot of assumptions for anything more than a small proof of concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the values you're going to be reading, `numpy` has no way to guess that as there is no metadata stored in the file itself. So in your case you have to do something like:

```py
x = np.fromfile(path, dtype=int)
```

If you're doing things like this, it's highly recommended to use fixed-size integers instead of just `int`, e.g. in C++ you can use `int32_t` from `<cstdint>` and in Python you can specify `int32` as dtype.

Comment: This, and you should also specify the byte order. On both sides.

Comment: Thanks! had to specify dtype=np.int32. Worked like a charm. 
    
    [ 0  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45] <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 3):

[`fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) assumes floating point numbers by default. If you want to change this behaviour, you need to pass in the type in the `dtype` named parameter.

As you're writing ints, this *should* work:

```
x = np.fromfile(path, dtype=int)
```